# How to unit test a method that updates a filter in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to unit test my `updateFilter()` method that is filtering an array based on a given value returned by every keystroke in an input field.

My method looks like this:

```
  updateFilter(e) {
    const v = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const t = this.t.filter((t) => {
      return t.id.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(v) !== -1 || !v;
    });
    this.data = t;
    this.content = this.data;
    this.table.offset = 0;
  }
```

I prepared my unit test like this and have no idea what to do next:

```
  describe('#updateFilter()', () => {
    it('format input string to lowercase', () => {

    });

    it('filter t array based on the given string ', () => {

    });

    it('offset should be 0', () => {

    });
  });
```

How could I build a meaningful test here?

Comment: is the method inside a component or service ? and did u tried out anything inside your 'it' functions like: expect(myClass.updateFilter('MOCKED STRING').toBe('mocked string'), for example in your first test ?

Comment: It's inside a component and I've tried a lot of things and the test failed. Furthermore I'm not sure how to build a meaningful test here that is testing the main goal of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `updateFilter` method being part of `FilterComponent` that has public members `content`, a test could look as follows.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('#updateFilter()', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterComponent>;
    let component: FilterComponent;
    let inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [FilterComponent]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        inputElement = <HTMLInputElement> fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('INPUT');
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('format input string to lowercase', fakeAsync(() => {

        //given
        component.t = ?; // no idea what this member is made of
        inputElement.value = 'abC'; 
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'C' });

        // when            
        inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        tick();

        // then
        expect(component.data).toBe(?); // define expected value here
    });

    ...
});
```